# OneNote link to excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-onenote, links

I've tried to link OneNote with Excel cell. It opens Excel workbook but not in specified cell and sheet. What is wrong whit my syntax?

```
C:\Users\Slawomir\Documents\Myexcel.xls#'sheet1' !F3
```

Comment: Perhaps the blank between `'` and `!`?

Comment: Erasing blank make no changes unfortunately.

Comment: Tried this syntax in Excel and it works (without blank). No idea why it doesn't work in OneNote...